# How do I add array items to object properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop

I want to do the following:

```
// an object
var object = {
    one: null,
    two: null,
    three: null
};

// an array
var array = ['this is one', 'this is two', 'this is three'];
```

I now want to merge them both together so I get;

```
var merged = {
    one: 'this is one',
    two: 'this is two',
    three: 'this is three'
};
```

I don't want to use any 3rd library just pure javascript (ECMA5).

**So what is the trick?**

Regards,
bodo

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear, please try to explain what it is you want to do exactly.

Comment: Do you want to see all properties when printed ? What command do you use for printing ?

Comment: +1 to @Jeroen. What do you mean by "parallel"?

Comment: Can you tell us what arguments is ?

Comment: What is `module: [object Object]` ?

Comment: By definition, the order of keys in an object is undefined, so this will be hacky in at least some way or the other. Any other approach on sourcing your pairs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
// an object 
var object = {
    one: null,
    two: null,
    three: null
};

// an array 
var array = ['this is one', 'this is two', 'this is three'];

function merge(arraysrc, array2dest) {

    var x, i = 0;

    var merged = [];

    for (x in array2dest) {
        var obj = {};
        obj[x] = arraysrc[i++];
        merged.push(obj);
    }
    return merged;
}

var a = merge(array, object);

alert(JSON.stringify(a));​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6mQYN/

Comment: Results might be unpredictable, object key order is not defined.

Comment: this is only a example how he can do this. Order, length have to be handled